# Accessing code behind property in server tags

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Is it possible to access a code behind property for a server tag?
I have a property on my code behind page that i want to pass into a javascript function i.e.

```
<asp:RadioButton onclick="moveToNextPage()" class="inputcell" Runat="server" ID="myRadioButton" Text="No"></asp:RadioButton>
```

So i want to be able to get the variable out of my code behind page and pass it to the "moveToNextPage()" function. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code behind value is `public` or `protected` then you can try this (assuming your variable is called `example`):

```
<asp:RadioButton onclick='<%= string.Format("moveToNextPage({0})", example) %>' class="inputcell" Runat="server" ID="myRadioButton" Text="No"></asp:RadioButton>
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I have placed a breakpoint on my property that i am querying and it never gets hit. Should it?

Comment: You might need to wrap '' around it if you are passing in a string value like moveToNextPage('{0}')

Comment: if you do view source do you see anything in the onclick event handler?

Comment: Are you checking for your breakpoint being hit when you click the radio button or when the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:RadioButton onclick='<%= string.Format("moveToNextPage({0})", yourproperty) %>' class="inputcell" Runat="server" ID="myRadioButton" Text="No"></asp:RadioButton>
```

Make sure your yourproperty is public

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I have placed a breakpoint on my property that i am querying and it never gets hit. Should it?

Comment: <asp:RadioButton onclick="moveToNextPage(<%=yourproperty%>)" class="inputcell" Runat="server" ID="myRadioButton" Text="No"></asp:RadioButton> Try alerting the value in javascript function

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:RadioButton onclick='<%# string.Format("moveToNextPage({0})", yourproperty) %>' class="inputcell" Runat="server" ID="myRadioButton" Text="No"></asp:RadioButton>
```

Important change would be <%# instead of <%=.  In order for this to work, you need to call myRadioButton.DataBind() somewhere in code behind